# Jquery function effect not being applied to dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am using this

```
http://vadikom.com/tools/poshy-tip-jquery-plugin-for-stylish-tooltips/
```

to load tips . this plugin works fine when the page is loaded and the tip gets applied to specific id or class or element but when i perform other functions using jquery and load more classes of the same name then this tip will not get applied but if the same element is present when page is loaded it works

so far ive done these

```
$('img').delegate('img', 'hover', function() {


$(this).poshytip({
                className: 'tip-twitter',
                showTimeout: 1,
                alignTo: 'target',
                alignX: 'center',
                offsetY: 5,
                allowTipHover: false,
                fade: false,
                slide: false
            });

       // code here
    });
```

//-----------------------------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.classname').poshytip({
                    className: 'tip-twitter',


    showTimeout: 1,
                alignTo: 'target',
                alignX: 'center',
                offsetY: 5,
                allowTipHover: false,
                fade: false,
                slide: false
            });
});
```

when i load another class with same name after say an ajax call this effect is not applied

Any help would be appreciated guys

Answer (score 0):

You're only binding the hover function to content that is visible at page load. Bind it again as a success to the ajax call.